# How would you use sort() command in Geany ubuntu and make it works successfully?

Tags: python

I am having some trouble trying to sort out a list. The simple command sort() seems not to work properly in the current environment I am working in. I am using Geany compiler of Ubuntu, and the output is always 'None' value

```
x=[2,3,8,9,4.5,6]
print x.sort()

Output: None
```

I have used ipython and the result is the right one, however I don't know why Geany is not working with this command. I have tried to use sorted(), then the output is different, but I just simply want to know why 'sort()' doesn't get along with Geany, at least for me :)

Thanks and I hope you can help me.

Comment: If an answer solves your issue, please accept an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort()` sorts the list `x` inplace, meaning it does not return any value (so it's `None`), but `x` is sorted now.

See the documentation: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

```
x = [2,3,8,9,4.5,6]
print x.sort()
>>> None
print x
>>> [2, 3, 4.5, 6, 8, 9]
```

What you can use if you want a return value is `sorted()`

```
x = [2,3,8,9,4.5,6]
print sorted(x)
>>> [2, 3, 4.5, 6, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Beat me to it, was literally writing my answer as you posted :)

Comment: Ok, it was. I knew it had to be quite simple. Thanks